# Android Sqlite rawquery selection args[] with "WHERE x IN(y)"

Tags: android, sqlite

Is it possible to use the questionmark (?) parameter together with `WHERE x IN(y)` when you want to replace "y" with an arbitrary number of parameters?

I've tried the following which not so surprisingly doesn't work:

```
String[] args = new String[]{"dude1, dude2"};
String query = "SELECT * FROM books WHERE author IN(?)";
db.rawQuery(query, args);
```

Is there a good way to do what I'm trying or am I forced to escape the args myself and concatenate them into the query string and not use ? or by generating a query string with the right number of ? depending on how many args I want?

Comment: `IN(?, ?)` or is the array length dynamic?

Comment: It's dynamic so I don't know the length at compile time.

Comment: The question this was marked as a duplicate of answered my question as well.